# Connect to socket.io admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

When I try to connect Socket.IO Admin UI that is what happens :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYqqf.png)
the server code :

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3001,{cors:
    {origin:["https://admin.socket.io","http://localhost:8080","http://192.168.227.1:8080"]},
    credentials:true  } )
const {instrument}  = require("@socket.io/admin-ui")

instrument(io,{auth:false});
```

I tried browser extensions for CORS enable but didn't work .

I want to access Sockect.IO Admin-UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `credentials` option is at the wrong place:

```
// BAD
const io = require('socket.io')(3001, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://admin.socket.io", "http://localhost:8080", "http://192.168.227.1:8080"
  },
  credentials: true
});
```

```
// GOOD
const io = require('socket.io')(3001, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://admin.socket.io", "http://localhost:8080", "http://192.168.227.1:8080",
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Reference: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#cors